# problems with php in a string assigned to a php variable

Tags: php, string, echo

I'm writing my first php page for class.  The page is supposed to take input from a form and output it.  At first I tried to using the $content variable below to store a block of html which would output either the form or the ouput.  I was putting this inside the id="content" div depending on whether or not the form elements were set.  Anyway, I moved away from this because I wasn't able to use the _SERVER['PHP_SELF'] varialbe correctly.  I'm abandoning this for now, but am now running into a similar problem.  Here' my code so far:

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST['first-name']) && !empty($_POST['last-name']) 
    && !empty($_POST['age']))
{
    $fname = $_POST['first-name'];
    $lname = $_POST['last-name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];

    $content = '<h1>About You</h1>
        <h4>First Name:</h4>
        <p><?php echo $fname; ?></p>
        <h4>Last Name:</h4>
        <p><?php echo $lname; ?></p>
        <h4>Age:</h4>
        <p><?php echo $age; ?></p>';
}
else
{
    $content = '';  
}

//get the first name, last name and age from the form


?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Personal Info Results</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>My Form</h1>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
            <div id="person-info">
                <label>First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="first-name"/><br/>
                <label>Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" name="last-name"/><br/>
                <label>Age:</label>
                <input type="text" name="age"/><br/>
            </div>
            <div id="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit Info"/></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="output">
        <?php echo $content; ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem right now is the fact that the echo function inside the $content variable isn't causing the output to appear.  Instead I'm getting blank lines.  Am I defining it incorrectly inside of the String assignment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$content = '<h1>About You</h1>
    <h4>First Name:</h4>
    <p><?php echo $fname; ?></p>
    <h4>Last Name:</h4>
    <p><?php echo $lname; ?></p>
    <h4>Age:</h4>
    <p><?php echo $age; ?></p>';
```

Should be

```
$content = '<h1>About You</h1>
    <h4>First Name:</h4>
    <p>'.$fname.'</p>
    <h4>Last Name:</h4>
    <p>'.$lname.'</p>
    <h4>Age:</h4>
    <p>'.$age.'</p>';
```

ECHO is not function and return nothing. Also you use `<?php ?>` construction inside PHP code. In this moment `<h1>About You</h1>` is not HTML, just string.

Comment: I was thinking of it differently.  I thought that once the string rendered as HTML the PHP would become active, but this makes sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this.

```php
$content = '<h1>About You</h1> <h4>First Name:</h4> <p>' . $fname 
    .'</p> <h4>Last Name:</h4> <p>' . $lname
    .'</p> <h4>>Age:</h4> <p>'. $age
    .'</p>';
```